# a:active not working with pseudo-element ::before child in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, pseudo-element

I would like to use icon fonts in `<a>` links. I have set up CSS rules for `a`, `a:hover` and `a:active`. However, `a:active` is triggered only when I click the links in Chrome, but not in Firefox and IE.

Example:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline;
}

a {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
a:active {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
}

.icon::before {
  content: "[icon]";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="icon"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

[Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwnmbzfL/23/)

Is this not supposed to be used like this? What's the recommend way?

Thank you!

PS. I am actually using icons from [icons8](https://icons8.com/). It has options other than using fonts which I will try later, but I would still like to know how to solve this if I want to use fonts.

**Edit:**

To my surprise, I found out that if I take out the `position: relative; top: 1px; left: 1px;` thing in `a:active`, then it works in Firefox (but still not in IE it seems)... Since the moving effect isn't important, I'll just not use it for now.

Also the other options icons8 provide are images and SVG set, which are not as handy as fonts when adjusting colors and sizes in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for informing me. I've added the code.

Comment: Interesting that this seems to affect more than one browser.

Comment: The problem is that the browser doesn't honor a click on the ::before. If you put some text in the content of the `a` after the icon, it does work when you click that. Let me think.

Comment: It's strange to me that `a:hover` is triggered on the pseudo `::before` element, whereas `a:active` isn't. Maybe click is just different than hover (and that different browsers do it differently)?